# What exactly is the "Filter" option in CUPS' printers.conf?

Tags: configuration, printing, cups, filter, printer

I just stumbled over the `Filter` option that one can add to a `<printer></printer>` in CUPS' `printers.conf`. It is described in the docs https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.7/ref-printers-conf.html#Filter, but I do not understand from the docs what it does exactly.

Is it doing the same as Tea4CUPS `filter:` functionality, making the package `cups-tea4cups` obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

A **cups filter** is

> The CUPS filter interface provides a standard method for adding support for new document types or printers to CUPS. Each filter is capable of converting from one or more input formats to another format that can either be printed directly or piped into another filter to get it to a printable format.

https://www.cups.org/doc/man-filter.html

---

**tea4cups's filter** on the other hand allows you to modify the data before it is passed to the printer, for example

> The sample filter below can remove the print job creation date from PostScript jobs, in order to more accurately detect duplicate jobs (so the MD5SUM would be identical from launch to launch)

(from tea4cups' example config)

tea4cups can do much more, it can execute commands before or after printing (for example waking up a network printer) which is not possible using plain cups.